# OSX: assign extension to content kind

Tags: macos, finder, file-association

Here I have a folder containing a bunch of *.mkv files (video, obviously) and *.srt files (subtitles, obviously). I want to keep them within one folder but I don’t want them to be mixed together. It looks like a good idea to visually arrange them into two separate groups.

However, neither extensions are recognised by the system, and they are still put under one group ‘Documents’, which is clearly not what I want.

The question: how to tell the system that all *.mkv file should be treated as ‘Media’ (or ‘Videos’, or whatever the name of the file kind group for video files)?

Thanks.[image]

EDIT:

@Daniel, the associated program is MPlayerX and the output of that command is as follows:

```
imac:Game of Thrones arnold$ mdls "Game of Thrones 1×2.mkv"
kMDItemContentCreationDate     = 2011-12-15 10:31:20 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate = 2011-12-27 09:09:55 +0000
kMDItemContentType             = "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge804450"
kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "public.data",
    "public.item"
)
kMDItemDateAdded               = 2011-12-27 09:22:55 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName             = "Game Of Thrones 1×2.mkv"
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate     = 2011-12-27 09:09:55 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate          = 2011-12-15 10:31:20 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode           = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags           = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon         = 0
kMDItemFSInvisible             = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden     = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery          = 0
kMDItemFSLabel                 = 0
kMDItemFSName                  = "Game of Thrones 1×2.mkv"
kMDItemFSNodeCount             = 220877659
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID          = 99
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID           = 99
kMDItemFSSize                  = 220877659
kMDItemFSTypeCode              = ""
kMDItemKind                    = "Video Media"
kMDItemLogicalSize             = 220877659
kMDItemPhysicalSize            = 220880896
imac:Game of Thrones arnold$
```

Weirdly enough, the ‘Item Kind’ does show up as ‘Video Media’. And for a subtitle file is is ‘Subtitle’. Still, it doesn’t help Finder arrange those files correctly for some reason…

Comment: What program is associated with these files? What's the output of `mdls` in Terminal for one of these files, e.g. `mdls "Game of Thrones episode 2.mkv"`?

Comment: Is this grouping feature new in Lion? The icons also say "Subtitles" and "Video", respectively, so it shouldn't really be a problem.

Comment: @slhck It's new in Lion. Icons are 100% images and provided by the associated application, so that doesn't mean anything. Arnold, thanks for the `mdls` output. Are you using *MPlayer OSX* or *MPlayer OSX Extended*?

Comment: @DanielBeck, it’s just the [regular MPlayerX from the App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/mplayerx/id421131143?mt=12).

Comment: @DanielBeck Ah, I thought it was represented by `kMDContentType`. What kind of content type is the one listed above though?

Comment: @slhck Dynamically generated, since the developer of MPlayerX didn't bother to properly assign a type. See my answer. That's why it's a *document*.

Comment: @DanielBeck
>see my answer
??

Comment: @ArnoldSakhnov Sorry about that. I posted a rather lengthy answer explaining the process but for some reason it didn't work when I tried and I deleted it for the time being. I probably got some detail wrong. If you're still interested, I can undelete it, but it currently is more of an explanation than a step-by-step guide.

Comment: @ArnoldSakhnov Finally I figured out the missing piece. Fixed the answer and undeleted it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use an application that declares the correct file type association for e.g. the `.mkv` file name extension.

For example, the system-defined file types in `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist` declare the following in the *Exported Type UTIs* section:

> [image]
>   [image]

This allows the system to associate the [UTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Type_Identifier) `public.jpeg` with the "UTI group" `public.image`, which is (very likely) what Finder uses for the *Images* group; the `public.filename-extensions` *equivalent type* maps to the file extension.

This allows OS X to determine, that `.jpg` file has the UTI `public.jpeg`, and that is a sub-UTI of `public.image` (and so on, with `public.item` and `public.data`). Finder then takes all the files that are (also) `public.image` and puts them in the same *Images* group.

The same applies to `public.mpeg-4` and `public.movie` and the filename mapping there.

---

Unfortunately, the author of MPlayerX didn't bother mapping the UTIs.

He didn't even bother creating proper file types for all the extensions the program supports. That's why in Finder's *list view*, all `.mkv` files *aren't* called e.g. *Matroska Video*, and have a matching *MKV* label on their icon, but simply *Video Media* with a generic *Video* label. All supported file types are listed by file extension for this "file format", so MPlayerX can open them:

> [image]

That means, for example, if you prefer playing `.m4a` files in MPlayerX to iTunes, you lose the descriptive *Apple MPEG-4 audio* in the Finder's *Kind* column and get *Audio Media* instead.

---

You can fix the grouping by editing the `/Applications/MPlayerX.app/Contents/Info.plist` file and properly declaring e.g. a `mplayerx.video` UTI that conforms to `public.movie` and adding the proper filename extension mapping.

You can fix the *Kind* column by editing the same file, and properly declaring file types with a better description, and creating an icon file for each.

Just use the *Core Types* `Info.plist` file as template, replacing e.g. `public.jpeg` with your own custom identifier (e.g. `mplayerx.video` if you don't want proper *Kind* columns and icons, or `mplayerx.mkv` if you want them). You need Xcode to edit these files, or convert them to XML editable in any text editor by using `plutil -convert xml1 <filename>`.

Your changes, which are rather easy to get wrong, will be overridden with every application update.

Alternatively, at least for the Finder *Arrange By Kind*, you can edit the core types definitions and add your own to it. Make sure to edit a copy of the file and replace it after editing to circumvent permissions issues. Be aware that you'll be editing and replacing core system files (i.e. asking for trouble) by doing this.

A saner solution would be to create a new "dummy" application that simply declares the file type UTIs as *Exported Type UTIs*. This will be used by OS X's file type database and you can update both OS X and MPlayerX without losing the content type associations. Even if you change e.g. `.m4a` to MPlayerX, only the *Kind* column is changed, it's still in the *Movie* category, due to the declarations in another application independent of the associated application.

So, create a new *application* e.g. using Automator that doesn't actually do anything when launched, and add the following to its `Contents/Info.plist` file:

> [image]

Save in `/Applications` or so, and restart Finder.

> [image]

Partial `mdls` output of the `.mkv` file, content type provided by the "helper app", item kind provided by the associated player (MPlayerX):

```
kMDItemContentType             = "superuser.371939.mkv"
kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "superuser.371939.mkv",
    "public.movie",
    "public.audiovisual-content",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
...
kMDItemKind                    = "Video Media"
```

---

Since this is just sloppy platform integration by the developer, you should probably file a bug.

Comment: Very interesting. Learned something new today. So that's why the `kMDItemContentTypeTree` doesn't add anything useful to the metadata?

Comment: @slhck Exactly. The system needs a way to associate the file with the content type UTI. That's missing, since it's not in the system by default (like e.g. `.mp4` is), and the application *adding* the file type to the system doesn't declare either the UTI (so it's just `dyn.xyz`) or the relation (so it's just `public.data`) either. They'd need to declare the UTI *and* associate it with `public.movie` (instead of e.g. `public.data`).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for such an informative and thorough research on the problem. This is very educational and helpful. I still yet to try out your solution, but I’m sure it’ll work. Very nice!

Comment: The hackiest of all hacks is to simply rename the `.mkv` to `.avi` **gasp!!!** I make it slightly less horrific by leaving a Spotlight Comment (in Get Info) saying it's really an mkv. ..this of course assumes your media player is okay with the wrong extension - VLC is down ;)

Comment: ...I forgot, you can also rename it to `.mkv.avi` for the least evil workaround but with a slightly less pretty filename.