# Changing mkv to video kind on mac

Tags: macos, mac, finder, file-association

I am trying to put mkv files under Video Category when arranging by kind on a mac. Here's what I added to info.plist of the Core Services

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
<string>mycustom.mkv</string>
<key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
<array>
    <string>public.movie</string>
</array>
<key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
<dict>
    <key>public.filename-extension</key>
    <string>mkv</string>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Even after a restart. The files don't show up as Movies.

I tried to follow the article 
[OSX: assign extension to content kind](https://superuser.com/questions/371892/osx-assign-extension-to-content-kind)

Can someone point out what I may be doing wrong here.

Comment: @LauriRanta actually I am using xcode to edit the files. I added it under **Exported Type UTIs**. I am using VLC. Can you let me know what player you are using. I can just install that and this will be fixed. I am on 10.8.2 as well. Thanks

Comment: The UTI for mkv is indy.jt.niceplayer.mkv even though I've removed [NicePlayer](http://code.google.com/p/niceplayer/). I've also installed [Perian](http://www.perian.org), [Movist](http://code.google.com/p/movist/), and [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html).

Comment: @LauriRanta Thanks. **NicePlayer** did the trick.